# Adding Events to google calendar using spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a script that will add events to calendar from active spreadsheet
I need to make an entry as 'Sent' if the Event has been scheduled post the script has been executed and not to reschedule the event looking at 'Sent' entry if the script ran again. Also, if it could look at an entry 'Pending' in the same column and not create an event for that entry

```
function addEvents() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar id ");
  
  var data = ss.getRange("A2:G" + lr).getValues();
  
    
  for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){
  
  var event =cal.createEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2],{location: data[i][3], description: data[i][4], guests: data[i][5], sendInvites: data[i][6]});
  

 {
    event.addGuest('xyz@gmail.com');
    
  } 
  }
}
```

Sample spreadsheet link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L8LMCbvszUaeMxinfpJrRZh10Rr_PqSqtRf8ct9rqZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Tried using the if else clause

```
if (data[i][6] = 'true') {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Q2:Q').setValue('Sent');}

  else{

  spreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Q2:Q').setValue('Pending')

  }
```